# glassfish v2 access control by IP

Tags: java, reverse-proxy, access-control-list, glassfish

How can I restrict access to some web-app deployed in Glassfish from certain IPs ?
Are there any internal access control in Glassfish or I need to proxy it with external nginx or Apache ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you are using a Virtual Server in glassfish then you can use allowRemoteAddress , denyRemoteAddress, allowRemoteHost and denyRemoteHost properties to deny/accept connections from certain IP's.

in Glassfish DAS go to configurations -> http-service-> Virtual Servers and then configure your properties there (under a non cluster glassfish the Virtual Servers are under Server configuration)